# Skipped function calls on Integer based frame data

Tags: c++, game-mechanics

I'm creating a basic animation system, where I call functions to change the rendered sprite and turn on hitboxes based on the current frame of the animation.

For example,  if (current_frame == 8), I turn on the hitbox. Then, if it hits something or if current_frame == 9, the hitbox is turned off.

However I've stumbled into a problem. If I implement an attack speed modifier, like, 20% attack speed increase, on 7th game update, the current_frame is 8.4 and I miss the function call to turn on the hitbox. I know I can implement something like (current_frame >= 8 && <= 9), but this doesn't work If I add an attack speed multipler of 100% or more - the frame will be skipped and functions wouldn't be called.

I'm also open for new animation systems / books / articles to study!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Have a second, integral frame counter.

After updating the original counter, gradually increment this new counter to match it, executing all your logic along the way:

```
for (; current_frame_int + 1 <= current_frame; current_frame_int++)
{
    // Add all your frame-based logic here.
}
```

---

**Option 2:** Have a flag to tell you if a specific step is already finished.

```
bool hitbox_shown = false;
```

```
if (current_frame >= 8 && !hitbox_shown)
{
    hitbox_shown = true;
    ShowHitbox();
}
```